# Multiple AIDL versions

Tags: android, aidl

The Android documentation for AIDL only states

> Caution: Any changes that you make to your AIDL interface after your first release must remain backward compatible in order to avoid breaking other applications that use your service. That is, because your .aidl file must be copied to other applications in order for them to access your service's interface, you must maintain support for the original interface.

So I tried some experiments. I have an existing AIDL interface and have implemented two IPC services that support it and can be accessed from my primary service.

So in the AIDL interface for my primary service, I added a method which was first in the list of pre-existing methods, built the app and deployed it. But the two IPC services were unchanged; they did not know about the new method. It did not work properly, but it did work. However, the original methods, when called, returned wrong values. It looked as if insertion of the new method at the top of the list was the problem (as if the entire package was marshaled in one byte array messing up the un-marshaling on the receive side).

So I added the new method as the last entry in the file instead, and this time it worked perfectly. Of course the old IPCs would not be able to handle the new method and if I called it a Remote Exception would probably be thrown.

So the question I have is why did the change in order make such a difference? Is this a fluke? Should it be impossible to add new methods under the same package? I don't want to have it work by adding a bunch of methods at the end of the file when that just happens to be an unintended fluke.

Answer (score 0):

The order of methods you declare in .aidl file should be the same in both client and service

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After gaining certain number of reputation points you will be able to post comments to other questions/answer.

Comment: I think you are right but I have nothing to back it up except experience.

Answer (score 0):

The aidl files on client and server sides are linked by position and would check the arguments when routing the calls.

```
client AIDL  <->   Server AIDL
methodA            methodB
methodB            methodA
```

If you have positions swapped as above, and the arguments could still apply, the client call methodA would then route to methodB on the Server side.

I did find any official document about this behavior. It is based on my experiences on Android R.